# preventDefault is disabling scroll of wrapping element (mobile)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile

I have a scroll-able grid of images where a regular click/tap links a zoom view, and performing a long-press links to a grid of menu items.

The issue is that when you long-press a click registers after the redirect and will select the menu item in the same location as where the long-press was initiated. This can be fixed with `preventDefault()` though, that then disables the ability to scroll the grid of images.

I would think that `stopPropagation()` would be the fix there, but to no avail.

This issue only occurs on mobile browsers (target here being chrome on current iOS devices). Works just fine on desktop browser.

```
class LongPress extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { timeout: null }

    this.handleLongpressCancel = this.handleLongpressCancel.bind(this);
    this.handleLongpressTimer = this.handleLongpressTimer.bind(this);
  }

  handleLongpressTimer(e) {
    e.persist();  // omitted code that relies on this to keep event obj
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      timeout: setTimeout(() => {
        // navigate to menu grid
      }, 500)
    })
  }

  handleLongpressCancel(_e) {
    clearTimeout(this.state.timeout);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={el => { this.wrapper = findDOMNode(el) }}
        onMouseDown={this.handleLongpressTimer}
        onTouchStart={this.handleLongpressTimer}
        onMouseUp={this.handleLongpressCancel}
        onTouchEnd={this.handleLongpressCancel}
        onTouchMove={this.handleLongpressCancel}
      >
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is where that LongPress component is used and also the styles that allow for scrolling.

```
...

render() {
    const wrapperStyles = {
      height: '100%',
      overflowY: 'scroll',
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      alignContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }

     return (
      <div style={wrapperStyles}>
        <LongPress
          styles={{ margin: 'auto', position: 'relative' }}
          ref={el => { this.imageGrid = findDOMNode(el) }}
        >
          { images }
        </LongPress>
      </div>
     );
   }
 }
```